# C++ : Using void to create variables

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ on my own from the internet. I was wondering if you can create a variable of the `void` type. If so , how can you? Also what will be these variables used for?

**This does not work:**

```
void b;
cout<<b;
```

**Error:**

> Size of b is unknown or zero

Thanks :)

Comment: What should a `void` variable actually be?

Comment: No you cannot. You can create a void pointer, but that should be avoided in modern C++.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ precisely . even i want to know abt it

Comment: ... an episode of Star Trek!?

Comment: @NeilKirk so wat is a void pointer used for?

Comment: You should think of `void` as representing *the absence of a variable*.

Comment: c++ tastes best when it's used as a statically-typed language

Comment: You can have a [void return type or expression](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20478193/1708801) but not a void object.

Comment: @DrewDormann i think my teacher told me it is possible to create a variable of void type . He told he will teach us later

Comment: @0mniscient okay, so can you add that context to the question, is makes more sense then.

Comment: If you want to use `void` so much, you can use it when declaring functions that don't have any arguments: `int test(void)` or don't return any value: `void test(int)`.

Comment: *"I am learning C++ on my own from the internet."* - Be kind to yourself, get one of the recommended books: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 5):

> *"I was wondering if you can create a variable of the void type."*

No, the compiler already told you.

> *If so , how can you?"*

See above.

> *"Also what will be these variables used for?"*

It won't be useful, because `void` explicitly designates *no type*.

---

> *"so wat is a void pointer used for?"*

As for your comment:

It's used to store the address of an object of any type. Unless you don't know the exact original type, it's pretty useless as well.

Answer (score 2):

> i think my teacher told me it is possible to create a variable of void type . He told he will teach us later

We can not have void objects, most likely what your teacher meant was that you can have a void expression or a void pointer. void expressions are very useful for templates when a function return different types, for example see the question: [Returning a void?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20478193/1708801) which provides the following code:

```
template <class T>
struct Test
{
    static constexpr T f() {return T();} 
};

int main()
{
    Test<void> test;
    test.f(); // Why not an error?
    return 0;
}
```

For reference the draft C++ standard says the following (*emphasis mine*):

> An **object type** is a (possibly cv-qualified) type that is not a function type, not a reference type, and **not a
>   void type.**

and:

> The void type has an empty set of values. The **void type is an incomplete type that cannot be completed**. It
>   is used as the return type for functions that do not return a value. Any expression can be explicitly converted
>   to type cv void (5.4). An **expression of type void shall be used only** as an expression statement (6.2), as an
>   operand of a comma expression (5.18), as a second or third operand of ?: (5.16), as the operand of typeid
>   or decltype, as the expression in a return statement (6.6.3) for a function with the return type void, or as
>   the operand of an explicit conversion to type cv void

The other possibility is your teacher was referring to void pointers, which is used when you need a pointer that can point to any type. Most likely for using C APIs, see [when to use void* in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17330777/1708801):

> Compound types can be constructed in the following ways:

and:

> pointers to void or objects or functions (including static members of classes) of a given type

Answer (score 2):

Here's the deal (and folks, this is a legit beginner question, jaysus, lay off the guy.)

The `void` type in C and C++ is a tag or label for "thing of no type at all." Now, when we talk about the "type" of something, we're really saying two things:

- how much memory does it occupy?
- what operations can we perform on that thing?

So, for example, when we declare something like `int x;` we're saying that `x`

- is `sizeof(int)` × 8 bits of memory
- has arithmetic operations like `*` and `+`.

Now, an object of *no* type would have neither one, so the compiler tells you the size is unknown or 0.

But what **is** useful is to have an *address* that doesn't have a type associated with it.  When you declare something as `int * xp;` you're saying thet `xp` is the address of something that we agree to treat as an `int` -- but it's just an agreement because we can, eg with a typecast, change or minds later.

When we declare something `void * vp;`, we're saying "this is the address of something, type of that something to be determined later."

Answer (score 0):

You can use **void** pointers to achieve that.
Check here:

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/613-void-pointers/

```
int nValue;
float fValue;

struct Something
{
    int nValue;
    float fValue;
};

Something sValue;

void *pVoid;
pVoid = &nValue; // valid
pVoid = &fValue; // valid
pVoid = &sValue; // valid
```

Using void pointers usually is a **bad practice**. It's a valid practice (in pre-C++11 standards) only for function pointers. 
Stay with hard typed pointers, because the compilers can perform optimizations on them.

Comment: Please Please in C++ land do not use void pointers. Give the compiler a fighting chance

Comment: @EdHeal i know it's a bad practice. It was just the answer to the question, I was just giving a proof that it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

**`void` is not valid for variable types other than `void*`s in C++, never for an actual value type.**

http://www.cplusplus.com has a good section on `void*`s: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/#void

Note that the lines:

> The data pointed by them cannot be directly dereferenced (which is logical, since we have no type to dereference to), and for that reason, any address in a void pointer needs to be transformed into some other pointer type that points to a concrete data type before being dereferenced.

A `void*` is typically used to reference values of an *unknown* type. Other information is used to determine the type, the `void*` is cast to that type and only then can be dereferenced.

This behavior was very common in C, however with the advent of C++ it is vastly preferable to use templates to determine the value type of anything that is known at compile-time, `void*`s are used only in the special case that a value type must be determined at run-time.

---

I've been learning about aliasing a lot lately, and it may be further evidence of `void*`'s fall from grace that it is not listed as a supported type while `char*` and `unsigned char*` are: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing

Comment: @JohanLundberg Lol, I should probably put a comment on that. I wrote the answer thinking about variable types, not function definitions.

Answer (score 0):

An example of use of void* in modern C++, which is ok (says our local C++ guru):

When creating portable code you sometimes want to know if your code was compiled as 32bit or 64bit, one way of determining this is to check the size of a void* as it represents the size of an address in bytes.
When

```
sizeof(void*)==8
```

you know your code is compiled as 64bit (8bytes). And When

```
sizeof(void*)==4
```

you know your code is compiled as 32bit